# Force the output of an SR latch with a Zener diode

Tags: digital-logic, power-electronics

I have an SR latch with a Zener diode placed as in the image below.

Someone told me that this configuration is used to force the output of the latch SR to a given state at the initial time.

Is that correct? If yes, how does it work?

[image: Latch SR]

Comment: Depends on zener voltage. And the resistance. And the exact chip type. TTL, CMOS, which subtype, provide a part number for the IC and zener.

Answer (score 0):

Been doing this since the 60's, and I've never heard of that trick.  Also, it won't work.

What will work is reversing the zener diode.  Now, whenever Vo2 is high, the zener diode will forward-conduct and the upper gate (reference designators!) input will be high.  Importantly, when V02 is low the diode will not conduct because the zener voltage is equal to or greater than VCC, but R will pull the upper gate input low.  This is the action that forces the ff to a known state at power-on.

Two things:

1. The diode does not have to be a zener.  Any small signal diode, regular of Shottkey, will work if its switching speed is fast enough for whatever the circuit is doing.  In a low-voltage circuit, such as 3.3 V, the Vf of a standard diode might be too large to guarantee operation; better to use a Shottkey.
2. This will not do anything if either the S and R inputs are connected to a devices or component that produces a firm low state at power-up.  The circuit is intended for an application with something like two switch inputs, where both the S and R inputs are simply pulled high by resistors at power-on.